# Java 8 Stream Collectors for Maps, misleading groupingBy error

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm pretty confused by the differences in these two methods, but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

I have a working example, and a non-working example below. In the working example, I'm assigning the variable tester as a "Map", In the non-working example I'm trying to assign it to Map. In the second example, the error is shown here:

[image: Screenshot]

I am failing to see the connection between the types for the tester variable, and the type of the myMap variable.

```
//Working Example (or at least it compiles)
public String execute(Map<String, String>  hostProps) {
        Map tester = usages.stream()
            .map(usage -> prepareUsageForOutput(usage, rateCard.get()))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(myMap -> myMap.get("meterName")));    // This case compiles
}

//Compiler Error, just by adding the Map types on line 13, it breaks line 18
public String execute(Map<String, String>  hostProps) {
        Map<String, Object> tester = usages.stream()
            .map(usage -> prepareUsageForOutput(usage, rateCard.get()))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(myMap -> myMap.get("meterName")));   // In this case, the .get() method call can't resolve .get. It doesn't recognize that myMap is a Map. 
}


//This is the method that gets called in the above methods
static Map<String, Object> prepareUsageForOutput(Usage usage, RateCard rateCard ){

}
```

### Update 1 - Wrong Collector Method

While Eran posted the explanation of my original issue, it revealed that I should have been using Collectors.toMap instead of Collectors.groupBy, because my goal was to return a map entry for each map returned from "prepare", where the key was a string, and the value was the map returned from "prepare". groupBy will always return a list of results as the map value.

I also removed the filter statements, as they were irrelevant and significantly complicated the example.

This was the final result that met my goal:

```
Map<String, Object> tester = usages.stream()
     .map(usage -> prepareUsageForOutput(usage, rateCard.get()))
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(myMap ->(String)myMap.get("meterName"), Function.identity()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `prepareUsageForOutput` returns a `Map<String, Object>`, this means the `Collectors.groupingBy()` collector operates on a `Stream<Map<String, Object>>`, which means it creates a `Map<Object,List<Map<String, Object>>>`, not a `Map<String, Object>`.

This answer doesn't explain the error your compiler gave, but several times I encountered misleading compilation errors where `Stream`s are involved, so I suggest changing the output type to `Map<Object,List<Map<String, Object>>>` and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Wow that makes a bit more sense now.  Actually, the result I want from collect() is a Map<String,Object>. Each map that comes back from "prepare" has a key named "meterName".  I want those values that to be the "key" in the final map. Now I can't seem to think of a way to achieve that. I've tried entrySet and flatmap, but I can't make sense of that either.

Comment: @solvingJ Does `myMap.get("meterName")` return a `String`? And what do you want the value of the final Map to be?

Comment: Yes, the keys are a string, and the final map would have keys that correspond to the values of the get("meterNames") calls and the values would be the original maps.  I think Function.identity() would be appropriate.

Comment: @solvingJ I had a mistake in my original answer. `groupingBy` would return a `Map<Object,List<Map<String, Object>>>`, not a `Map<Object,Map<String, Object>>`.

Comment: Yes, but you made me realize where I my thinking was bad.  I also had a second problem is that I was trying to use Collectors.groupingBy when I should have been using Collectors.toMap. I will update the post with the final solution. Thanks!